# Pl/Sql_StoredProcedure_table update based on condition

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have written a plsql procedure in which i want to update columns c1, c2 in table1 with the corresponding values from table2 which are connected by foreign key. If the row does not exist in table2, then I want to set value of c3 of table1 itself to c2. In that case no need to update anything to c1. Could you please help me to do that.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_table1
IS

BEGIN
  FOR t1_record IN (SELECT * FROM table1)
  LOOP
    IF t1_record.c2 is not null THEN
      UPDATE table1 x SET(c1, c2) = (SELECT y.id, y.name FROM table2 y WHERE y.id=t1_record.c2)
      WHERE x.id = t1_record.id AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table2 y WHERE y.id=t1_record.c2);

       -- Need to write else condition here for the inner if -----
    ElSIF 
       ---------------------
       -----------
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you put it & the way I understood the question, it is not `ELSIF` you need but yet another `UPDATE` within the same `IF`, but this time with `NOT EXISTS`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_table1
IS
BEGIN
   FOR t1_record IN (SELECT * FROM table1)
   LOOP
      IF t1_record.c2 IS NOT NULL
      THEN
         UPDATE table1 x
            SET (c1, c2) =
                   (SELECT y.id, y.name
                      FROM table2 y
                     WHERE y.id = t1_record.c2)
          WHERE     x.id = t1_record.id
                AND EXISTS
                       (SELECT 1
                          FROM table2 y
                         WHERE y.id = t1_record.c2);

         UPDATE table1 x
            SET c3 = c2
          WHERE     x.id = t1_record.id
                AND NOT EXISTS
                       (SELECT 1
                          FROM table2 y
                         WHERE y.id = t1_record.c2);
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why loop? use `merge` as follows:

```
merge into table1 x
using (select x.id, x.c3, y.id, y.name 
        from table1 x left join tabl2 y
          on x.id = y.id) y
on (x.id = y.id)
when matched then
update set x.c1 = coalesce(y.id,x.c1), c2 = coalesce(y.name, x.c3);
```